# Is it possible to disable PHP slow log per script?

Tags: php, performance, logging, fpm, ini-set

I have one script on my webpage which process a lot of informations and It should be slow. But php-fpm is terminating it, because of slow log.

I just see in logs  NOTICE: child 26537 stopped for tracing and web server throws me 504 error.

I tried to disable slow log by ini_set

```
 ini_set('request_slowlog_timeout',0);
```

but it is not working. 
I am using php 7.1 latest version

Comment: If something like that is slow you should think about moving it to some kind of message queue arrangement so it can be done without keeping the user waiting for a response.

Answer (score -2):

You try do do with php.ini (no report log errors)

```
ini_set("log_errors", 0);
```

what you can to do on your vhost configuration example : (mean no output log generate for this host)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@myapp.dev
    ServerName myapp.dev
    ServerAlias www.myapp.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/vagrant/code/public
    ErrorLog /dev/null
    CustomLog /dev/null common
</VirtualHost>
```

For the slow logs, try to solve why you got some slow log and add a strategic action on PHP code for this.
Regards.